# PHP - Use isset inside function not working..?

Tags: php, function

I have a PHP script that when loaded, check first if it was loaded via a POST, if not if GET['id'] is a number.

Now I know I could do this like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) AND isNum($_GET['id'])) { ... }

function isNum($data) {  
    $data = sanitize($data);
    if ( ctype_digit($data) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I would like to do it this way:

```
if(isNum($_GET['id'])) { ... }

function isNum($data) {  
    if ( isset($data) ) {
        $data = sanitize($data);
        if ( ctype_digit($data) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I try it this way, if $_GET['id'] isn't set, I get a warning of undefined index: id...  It's like as soon as I put my $_GET['id'] within my function call, it sends a warning... Even though my function will check if that var is set or not...

Is there another way to do what I want to do, or am I forced to always check isset then add my other requirements..??

Comment: besides your actual problem: instead of "if (<condition>) { return true; } else { return false; }" you can just write "return <condition>;" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always include a convenience function that a few other languages provide: get.

```
function get($needle, $haystack, $return=null) {
    return array_key_exists($needle, $haystack) ? $haystack[$needle] : $return;
}
```

Now you can call:

```
if(isNum(get('id', $_GET))) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

You can change `isNum` to receive the parameter by reference

```
<?php

if(isNum($_GET['id'])) { ... }

function isNum(&$data) {
    if (isset($data) ) {
        $data = sanitize($data);
        return ctype_digit($data);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, `$_GET['id']` will be implicitly created on call and initialized to `NULL`.

If you're not OK with that or with the hacky nature of this solution, go with some other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the improved code. (sanitize after isset, return ctype_digit()...)

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing an undefined index while passing it initially. You could do this:

```
$key = 'id';

function foo($id ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET[$id] ) ) { 
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just do isset before the function call.

```
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && isNum($_GET['id'])) { }
```

Another option, use a temporary variable:

```
$foo = isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
if ( $foo ) { functionCall($foo); }
```

You can also tone down the error reporting levels if it doesn't concern you that much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an elegant way of doing it using a custom class:

First, define a SmartArray class:

```
class SmartArray extends ArrayObject {
    public static function convert(&$array) {
        $array = new self($array);
    }
    public function offsetGet($index) {
        return $this->offsetExists($index)? parent::offsetGet($index):NULL;
    }
}
```

Then simply call:

```
SmartArray::convert($_GET);
```

Now your `if(isNum($_GET['id'])) { ... }` won't complain anymore if $_GET doesn't have the key 'id' :)

Answer (score -2):

This is what you want, check to make sure the id is set BEFORE the call to `isNum`:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isNum($_GET['id'])) {
...
}
```

Comment: He knows that. He wanted to _avoid_ that, too!